# Is it possible to write multiple variables inside a path when saving document in uipath

Tags: automation, filepath, uipath

I am in the process of saving a pdf-file after downloading it on the browser. I have to put in two variables inside the file path (gotten from excel sheet, column A and B) to be able to save it in the right folder. Uipath will somehow not allow me to save it. Is there something wrong with the way I am typing in the variables inside or do I have to try another way?

BR

Salam Katawazi

Comment: Please don't add external links. No one want to hover over external links. Top of it they are dead after sometime and question is of no use.

Comment: okay, thank you for your comment. I am a new user, so I tried to attach images, but it did not work.

Comment: this is the path I want to type in: "\\tsclient\H\tekst\Klienter\" + row.Item(0).ToString + " " + row.Item(1).ToString + "\Regnskab\2019"

Comment: I just tried your example from the comment above and worked fine without any issues. Maybe you want to attach an image to your post (it is easily done via the <img> tag?

Comment: try to use row(0).ToString instead row.Item(0).ToString and row(1).ToString

Comment: @НиколайНунев Thank you very much, it worked that way. But now there is another problem. Whenever I log onto the client profile through column(5) it returns an error because I am not authorised to their profile, I want to skip that row(client) and continue to next row. I have tried with retry scope but it did not work. How do I begin the loop again with the next row in the column?

Comment: I can't imagine the whole process that you are trying to execute, but if you are just trying to skip a field try this:  the activity --> properties (upper right corner) --> continue on error = true

Comment: I tried the 'continue' activity and it worked just fine. It is difficult to imagine since I don't have any images. I will see if I can do that next time. Thank you for all your input.

Comment: Have you tried using Path.Combine instead of adding strings togehter? It might be an issue with the backslashes since these are escape characters so removing them and using Path.Combine might solve your issues.
Otherwise try to replace single backslash with double backslash "\" => "\\" in all places.